# Ip routing in php

Tags: php, unix, phpmailer, ip-address, email

I have multiple Ip address in my server. I need  to select one of the ip address and trigger  send email to the user. Email send from specific Ip address
Example:

- 215.XXX.XXX.120
- 215.xxx.xxx.121
  -215.xxx.xxx.122

Example I select one of the ip address  like 215.xxx.xxx.120 and send a email from this ip address using php mail function

ip routing concept is not well documentation?.Please kindly provide  Which technology we could slove this problem to send via particular email using  specific Ip address

Comment: This is up to the default routes set up in your networking config, not PHP. This is especially true with PHP’s mail function as that does not use a network connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding here...

"Sending a mail from this IP" would mean, that mail server is running on the IP from where mails are delivered.

But the Sender of an email MUST be an email address, it cannot be a IP.
You could create an email account with the IP as part of the email address, f.e. '215.xxx.xxx.120@example.com'.

Comment: I think you’ve missed what the question is asking. This is about default IP routes, not email addresses.